# Saving the results of an SQL query to an Excel file on a button click

Tags: c#, sql, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Asp.Net MVC web application in which a web page has link `EXPORT` runs a C# function which has an SQL Query and exports the data to an excel file and saves on the local machine. Once the action of saving is completed it should return to page called admin and for some reasons it is not doing so and returning to an empty page

I have the following code in the controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult ExportWBData()
        {

                sqlcon.Open();
                string strGetAllWBData = @"select Product, Term, BidVolume, BidCP as BidCounterParty, Bid, Offer, OfferCP as OfferCounterParty, OfferVolume from CanadianCrudes";

                SqlCommand cmdGetAllWBData = new SqlCommand(strGetAllWBData, sqlcon);
                DataTable dtGetAllWBData = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter daGetAllWBData = new SqlDataAdapter();

                daGetAllWBData.SelectCommand = cmdGetAllWBData;
                daGetAllWBData.Fill(dtGetAllWBData);
                sqlcon.Close();

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
                worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
                worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

                for (int i = 0; i < dtGetAllWBData.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dtGetAllWBData.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[1, j + 1] = dtGetAllWBData.Columns[j].ToString();
                        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dtGetAllWBData.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                    }
                }

                string fromFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                string toFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy";

                DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Today.ToString(fromFormat), fromFormat, null);


                string filedate = newDate.ToString(toFormat);


                workbook.SaveAs(@"Z:\WBDomesticDumps\WBData " + filedate + ".xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                workbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                app.Quit();

                return Admin();  
        }
```

Layout Page is

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Export", "ExportWBData", "Home")</li>
```

May I know a better way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, imo, is to create a view that writes an HTML table of your data. if you then set the content-type header to `application/vnd.ms-excel` then most browsers will recognize it as an excel file and prompt you to open or save.

The plus side of this is that you can use regular View templating (razor or otherwise) to manage your view logic and your controller logic winds up being a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Fix
 replace

`return Admin()` 
with

```
return RedirectToAction("Admin","Home");
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, code-only answers are generally not useful to future visitors. It is better to explain what the code does and why this is the best solution for the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your Excel function looks fine. I believe the issue is with your return.

It should be more like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Admin");
```